# With redirection (301), what I wrote to http header is gone in PHP

Tags: php, http-redirect

In an endpoint of my web service, I am adding some line to http response header and then it is redirected to another url in the service. This is 301 redirection and the header I wrote is removed somehow when this 301 response is sent to the browser.

I am calling header function in PHP to write to header and then calling redirect for 301 redirect. Is there any step I missed? Here is a rough flow:

```
header("X-my_custom_header:blahblah");
redirect($new_url);
```

redirect function is calling 3 header functions:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header( "Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Location: ".$new_url);
```

New Finding:

If I move the new header addition line inside redirection function (as 4th line in the function), then I can see the line.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: redirecting with the 301 overwrites any existing header

Comment: You've missed the step that shows the code your question is about.

Comment: Do you have any code executed after the `header` function? It can send some other headers back, overwriting the initial one.

Comment: What is `redirect`? Does it send the same `my_custom_header`? Also, if you server has a caching proxy in front (like nginx) - I think it could strip unknown headers.

Comment: FYI: If you have to use custom headers (what sense this should make here exactly is still unclear), use a name that starts with `X-` – that’s how you’re supposed to do that, to avoid conflicts with existing or future officially specified ones.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I added code snippet to make it clearer. I do have nginx which is trying to extract this header line and then log it. Yes, I am using a header name starting with "X-".

Comment: what do you use your custom header for? would sessions work?

Comment: my header is to log a user info. I can put this into session as suggested but it didsn't work somehow either. Probably the issue lies somewhere else in the code :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 301 redirect triggers a new request from the browser. Accordingly a new response is created on the server and this new response does not have any of the headers generated as part of the 301 response.

If you need to persist some data, you will need to either store it in the session or pass it via GET parameters on the 301 URL.

Comment: I think it makes sense that the response for the new request doesn't contain it. What I am interested in the very first response to the browser.

Comment: Perhaps use an HttpResponse instance to build the headers and log that object to check what PHP is sending.